# Application crashes when using hooked function with cout

Tags: c++, winapi, x86, hook, inline-assembly

I'm trying to hook a function using its address, and so far it is overall working great!

The only problem is when using `std::cout` in combination with having `MessageBoxA` from the WinAPI hooked, then it crashes! The weird thing is, it only crashes in that specific case, not if it is called in combination with `printf` or simply `int i = MessageBoxA(...);`

For testing, I made so that the instructions at the function address directly returns `32`. *Not much of  a hook I know, but this is just for testing.*

```
// mov eax, 32
// ret
const DWORD instructionCount = 6;
BYTE instructions[instructionCount] = { 0xB8, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC3 };
```

Besides having to change protection on a region with `VirtualProtect()`, then
now I basically just do

```
memcpy(MessageBoxA, instructions, instructionCount);
```

Now testing it using this:

```
int i = MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hello World", "Injector", MB_OK);

printf("Works: %d\n", i);
printf("Works: %d\n", MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hello World", "Injector", MB_OK));

std::cout << "Works: " << i << std::endl;
std::cout << "Doesn't: " << MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hello World", "Injector", MB_OK) << std::endl;

printf("Hello World\n");
```

Then it crashes just after `std::cout << MessageBoxA(...)`. Removing that line, and everything works!

*Note that it successfully prints `32`, it crashes when reaching the next statement.*

[image: Application Crash]

Again it is only in that case where it doesn't work, so using this:

```
__declspec(noinline) int testFunction(int i)
{
    return i;
}
```

Then reusing the above code and changing `MessageBoxA` to `testFunction` (as well as the arguments), and now all 4 statements work!

---

Bottom line, does anybody have any ideas for why and what is causing the crash in that specific case? When the other cases work perfectly fine.

Comment: run it in a debugger, and show us the asm, registers, and stack backtrace at the point where it crashes.  What calling convention does MessageBoxA use?  Is it supposed to pop its args off the stack?  If so, the calling code will push args and be expecting the called function to clean up the stack (only applicable to 32bit code, since the win64 ABI puts the first 4 args in regs).

Comment: Does `std::cout << "Doesn't: " << (int)MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hello World", "Injector", MB_OK) << std::endl;` Work?

Comment: @AdamMartin results in the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're corrupting the stack pointer.  Try using the following:

```
const DWORD instructionCount = 8;
BYTE instructions[instructionCount] = { 0xB8, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC2, 0x10, 0x0 };
```

That will pop the args off the stack as Peter Cordes mentioned.  Hope that helps.

Comment: While I understood @PeterCordes comment, I couldn't visualize how to fix it (I never work with assembly). But you answer does the trick! Many thanks!